# ArgumentError (method 'sort!': given 0, expected 1) when sending a confirmation mail via Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

I'm developing a Rails 4 app with Devise.
I wanted to start using confirmable, but whenever it's sending out a confirmation email,
it throws said ArgumentError.

Stacktrace:

```
ArgumentError (method 'sort!': given 0, expected 1):
kernel/common/enumerable.rb:260:in `sort_by'
mail (2.6.1) lib/mail/parts_list.rb:36:in `sort!'
mail (2.6.1) lib/mail/message.rb:1789:in `ready_to_send!'
mail (2.6.1) lib/mail/message.rb:1806:in `encoded'
actionmailer (4.1.6) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:546:in `set_payload_for_mail'
actionmailer (4.1.6) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:526:in `deliver_mail'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionmailer (4.1.6) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
mail (2.6.1) lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:158:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `make_lambda'
<...>
```

I'm using rbx 2.2.10

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error using rbx-2.2.10 and Rails 4.16. Seems to be a bug in the 'mail' gem which for me was a dependency of devise-invitable. (

```
bundle dependency mail --reverse-dependencies
```

and the above command again for actionmailer)

I got around this by specifying an older version of the mail gem in my Gemfile

```
gem 'mail', '~> 2.5.4'
```

And then running

```
bundle update mail
```

I've also raised an issue on the github page for mail : https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/803

-----Update----

if you are happy to work with their master branch -- on the edge -- this is fixed

`gem 'mail', github: 'mikel/mail', branch: 'master'`

Comment: same here. Downgrading mail helped

Comment: Apparently a pull request has been merged and fixed this issue - see https://github.com/mikel/mail/pull/782
But I have not tried updating mail yet.

Comment: working now off master branch thanks to merged pull request [#782] (github.com/mikel/mail/pull/782)
in my Gemfile
`gem 'mail', github: 'mikel/mail', branch: 'master'`